# modeling an excel table (dynamic columns and fixed rows)

Tags: database, excel, database-design

please help me finding the correct structure of a database table that allow to store the data of an excel table that looks like this:

[image]

first I tried to store rows and columns headers in tables:

```
rows(id_row, label)
columns(id_col, label)
```

then I created a table for storing values like this:

```
mytable(id_tbl, #id_row, #id_col, value, date_add)
```

but I realized that this solution need more processing to select and manipulate (deleting, edition) and maybe it will affect the performance of my code

and since I have a fixed rows, I decided to do it like this:

```
columns(id_col,label)
mytable(id_tbl, id_col, date_add, row_1, row_2, row_3)
```

so in order to store an instance of my excel table, I will need 1 row in the mytable table for each column

So is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A database table definition declares its columns, not the rows. Depending on what you are modeling and how you are going to use this table I would suggest one of these approaches.

A well-[normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) approach would be something like this:

```
mytable(unique_id, entity_label, value_label, column_value, [other entity attributes e.g. date_added])
```

Some decoding: `entity_label` is what you have in Excel Column A, `value_label` is what you have in Excel Row 1. Your data stored in this manner would look something like this:

```
unique_id  entity_label  value_label   column_value
1          row_1         col_1         9 
2          row_1         col_2         19 
3          row_1         col_3         29 
4          row_2         col_1         50
```

and so on.

This stores one and only one value (`column_value`) per database row, and is a flexible and extensible approach. For example, since `entity_label` and `value_label` are identified on each database row, it will effortlessly handle an arbitrary number of `value_labels` per entity (Excel "col_nn") and overall data points. It is a simple matter to sum all the `column_values` for an `entity_label` (as you seem to be doing in Excel Column E). Deleting, adding, and updating an entity or specific value within an entity are all possible and simple.

On the other hand it is possible your entity model always has three values per entity. Much as you have presented your source data, a table definition mimicking this approach could be this:

```
mytable(unique_id, entity_label, column_value_1, column_value_2, column_value_3, [other entity attributes e.g. date_added])
```

The major disadvantage of this approach is the lack of flexibility. For example, if the number of `value_labels` per entity ever changes (say, increases from 3 to 4), you might find yourself editing a lot of code just to take into account the entity's new column.

A mantra I like to repeat is "rows are cheap, columns are expensive." Keep this in mind as you design your database tables.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I tried to avoid the first approche because it seems to me that it will need more processing for CRUD operations but I will go for it since it's very flexible